Make speech to text without the azure or google service api
Hay,
Is there any way that i have a mp3 audio file (Bengali language) and i want to transcript it and get the output as text or text file.
I have GitHub student pack and the azure. But i do not want to use the azure account. Is there any way to make the mp3 file to text (Speech to text).
I do not want to use the azure account.

There's a GUI Python-powered app called Buzz on Git Hub that is downloadable for working offline. I use it regularly for transcription and sometimes translation, with and without audio stamps. You can drag audio or video files onto the UI. I see Bengali in the language list, though I can't vouch for its accuracy.
https://github.com/chidiwilliams/buzz/
